# ImportErrors when running Python code through VBA macro in Excel

Tags: python, excel, vba, import

I am facing import errors when trying to run Python code through a VBA macro in Excel. The Python code runs without any issues when executed directly in my Python IDE (e.g., PyCharm), but encounters import errors when triggered through the VBA macro. I have verified that the necessary Python environment is activated, and all required libraries (such as NumPy, Pandas, Pyomo) are installed in the environment.

I am using the following VBA-code:

```
Sub StartAllocation()
    Dim objShell As Object
    Dim PythonInterpreterPath As String
    Dim PythonScriptPath As String

    PythonInterpreterPath = """C:\Users\USER\.conda\envs\ATPZ\python.exe"""

    PythonScriptPath = """C:\Users\USER\Documents\PATH\run.py"""

    Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    objShell.Run "cmd.exe /k conda activate ATPZ && conda deactivate && " & PythonInterpreterPath & " " & PythonScriptPath, 1, True
End Sub
```

Here is an example of the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[YourUsername]\Documents\PATH\run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from run import run_optimization, generate_matrix, calc_regret
  ...
  File "C:\Users\[YourUsername]\.conda\envs\ATPZ\lib\site-packages\pyomo\environ\__init__.py", line 71, in _import_packages
    _do_import(pname)
  ...
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have double-checked the configuration of the VBA macro and ensured that the correct Python environment ('ATPZ') is activated. The necessary paths and variables in the VBA macro are also correctly set to point to the Python environment.

I suspect that there might be an issue with the interaction between the VBA macro and the Python environment.

I've tried a lot of code snippets from the internet, but the actual version is the most promising one right now.

Any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Possibly something on the Python side which is relying on a specific working folder/current directory which is not pointing to the same location when calling from VBA...